# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, testing, white-box

Hello am calling from a class to test my product however i keep getting this error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Testing:

```
global::OfficeSystem.Employees employees = new OfficeSystem.Employees();

employees.Delete(Convert.ToInt64("17")); <--- Primary Key
employees.GetEmployeeByOfficeID(Convert.ToInt64("6"));
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: We'd need to see what employees.Delete and employees.GetEmployeeByOfficeID do.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: You'll need to post the stack trace - none of the calls there can navigate over a null pointer.

Comment: We're going to need a tad more information here. What line is it occurring on,  have you verified a new instance of `Employees` is being created, etc.

Comment: The code that might be giving error is surely not here...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like for what ever reason you are not instantiating your object. I suggest run you code in debug and add a watch on employees to make sure its not zero. Hope that helps.

Comment: `employees` is getting instantiated in the first line - it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means you are using an object that is `null`. Accessing a member on `null` is never valid.

I'm not sure which line is causing the error. Is it the one that says "Primary Key"? If so, could employees be `null`? It should be extremely trivial to find out using the debugger.

If needed, check for `null` before using the object to prevent this error.

Comment: employees is getting instantiated in the first line - it is not null